# Grabbing PFFile and loading in default PFCollectionViewCell

Tags: parse-platform

I'm having trouble loading the image in a default `PFCollectionViewCell`. I'm using the `PFQueryCollectionViewController`, and has set up the stuff properly - except for the imageFile.

The default `PFCollectionViewCell` has two fields: the `PFImageView` and the `UILabel`.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFCollectionViewCell? {
  var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? PFCollectionViewCell
  if cell == nil {
    cell = PFCollectionViewCell()
  }
  let nom = object as! Nom
  cell?.imageView.file = nom.imageFile
  println(nom.imageFile) //prints the object id
  cell?.imageView.loadInBackground() //nothing actually loads

  cell?.textLabel.text = nom.createdBy.name //textlabel is populated properly
  return cell
}
```

1. I was able to populate the textField
2. I wasn't able to populate the imageView

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: You need to make sure you also put the placeholder image for it to load. You must set the `image` property of the `PFImageView`.

They should really document that...